# Convert between objc integers and C++ enums in Objective C++ code

Tags: c++, objective-c, enums

I have an Objective C selector which returns integers. I have a C++ instance method which expects an enum. How can I link them? I'm in an Objective C++ (.mm) class while I'm doing this.

I want to call this:

```
TKClass::foo(MyEnum enumVal) { ... }
```

With the return value of this:

```
- (int) intValue { ... }
```

Like this:

```
myCPPInstance->foo([myObjCInstance intValue]);
```

I've tried casting (`foo((MyEnum) [myObjCInstance integerValue])`) but it doesn't work. I definitely don't want my Objective C object to know anything about the enum; `intValue` needs to stay as an integer. Similarly, I don't really want to have the C++ method worry about integer inputs when it should be accepting enums.

I'm not much of a C++ programmer, so sorry if this is easy.

Thanks

EDIT: The enum is defined like this:

```
enum MyEnum { 
   Apples = 0,
   Bananas = 1,
   Chocolate = 2
};
```

Comment: When you try `foo((MyEnum) [myObjcInstance integerValue])`, what happens?

Comment: Compiler says "Missing [ at start of message send expression"

Comment: Oh hell it was a namespace issue. Thanks Rob - made me take a look at *all* the compiler errors, not just the first one.

Comment: Please post the answer as an answer rather than as an update to the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It was a namespace issue. The cast should have been:

```
myCPPInstance->foo((myNamespace::MyEnum) [myObjCInstance intValue]);
```